# Sum fields in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, summarizing

I need to merge fields in rows in the attribute table based on common values of some attributes and calculate the sum of the area associated to them. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you add some screenshot showing what you mean?

Comment: Is the table is in enterprise db?  If so, did you try using an SQL expression with `GROUP BY` on your common value with `SUM` on the fields you want summed?  I would recommend writing/debugging the sql in something like SSMS, then pasting it into the the UI or to the gp tool. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-query-table.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dissolve tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) to merge the similar values in the attribute table.  If the output is a file-geodatabase feature class then there will be a default attribute with the area total. If you output to a shapefile you can create a new attribute and use the [calculate geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) tools to calculate the area.